# Which cloud provider can be mounted with EncFS?

Tags: mount, cloud, encfs, online-storage

I remember that Ubuntu One could do that back in the days when it has storage features. Dropbox just syncs are folder with it Linux client. When using Google Drive with Grive2 it should be possible sync only the EncFS encrypte folder. Are there service that support that out of the box?

Comment: EncFS has serious breaches. When you install it Ubuntu will issue warnings about them. Make sure you understand them before you use it

Comment: @user334639 Has EncFS been broken? I haven't read that anywhere.  If you're referring to the security audit from 2014, some of the issues were fixed years ago (definitely disabling MACs & constant-time MACs), some are considered non-standard today & not a "best practice" or could be better (any attacker with repeated read-write access is trouble for any encryption). Apparently sparse files are still an issue for other newer programs like CryFS too, and eCryptfs just doesn't support sparse files so zero-fills them taking up more space.

Comment: It really comes down to your threat model - I wouldn't use EncFS *alone* to protect against a large government or corporation. The best security uses layers, including physical, and EncFS would make a good extra layer (maybe in between LUKS & PGP). It's more than capable on it's own against common smash & grab thieves & nosy friends & family.

Comment: @user334639 What would be an replacement to EncFS to securely store data at a cloud provider?

Comment: @Xen2050 and aggsol, I use EncFS to store all my passwords plus credit cards with security code and billing address inside Dropbox, it's very convenient. I started before this 2014 audit came out and I never bothered to change. But read about what kind for information might eventually leak and I made an informed decision to use it. You can make your informed decision too :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All the cloud storage services like DropBox basically mirror a specific local directory, so anything you can do with a local directory & files (sparse files and some file attributes might be problems) you can do with your local copy of cloud files. There were a couple that are supposed to support built-in encryption, but they hold the files and it's their software, so ultimately they control the security

Using just about any encryption should work, a LUKS/dm-crypt container, an EncFS folder (it may not be the best for cloud storage, see below), or an eCryptfs folder (though it usually keeps config files separately in `/home`), or [CryFS](https://www.cryfs.org) is new & appears specifically designed for cloud storage.

Comment: Some how I expected something like a remote NAS filesystem/protocol with build in encryption. CryFS looks like a good candidate but requires a trustworthy sync client.